# Apache rewrite rules not working for mqipt

Tags: ibm-mq, httpd.conf

I am using apache httpd for setting mqipt. Using the details given in docs, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=thru-apache-rewrite, I have setup everything. I am not using IBM caching proxy. Hit are going to IBM MQ but getting error

```
----- amqrmrsa.c : 974 --------------------------------------------------------
05/02/21 13:48:10 - Process(19315.2426) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(ibmmq-55ddff666-cscrk) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM1)
                    Time(2021-05-02T13:48:10.169Z)
                    RemoteHost(10.244.1.1)
                    CommentInsert1(_gateway (10.244.1.1))
                    CommentInsert2(TCP/IP)
                    CommentInsert3(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)

AMQ9209E: Connection to host '_gateway (10.244.1.1)' for channel
'DEV.APP.SVRCONN' closed.

EXPLANATION:
An error occurred receiving data from '_gateway (10.244.1.1)' over TCP/IP.  The
connection to the remote host has unexpectedly terminated.

The channel name is 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN'; in some cases it cannot be determined
and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Tell the systems administrator.
----- amqcccxa.c : 2730 -------------------------------------------------------
05/02/21 13:48:10 - Process(19315.2426) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(ibmmq-55ddff666-cscrk) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM1)
                    Time(2021-05-02T13:48:10.170Z)
                    CommentInsert1(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)
                    CommentInsert2(19315)
                    CommentInsert3(10.244.1.1)

AMQ9999E: Channel 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN' to host '10.244.1.1' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 19315 for channel
'DEV.APP.SVRCONN' ended abnormally. The host name is '10.244.1.1'; in some
cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 974 --------------------------------------------------------
```

This looks like problem between mqipt2 to IBM MQ server.

I have also tried by removing apache httpd and sending message from application to mqipt1 -> mqipt2 -> IBM MQ, and it is working but only when I am using apache httpd from mqipt1 -> apache -> mqipt2 -> IBM MQ then it fails

Comment: The instructions you reference do use the IBM caching proxy, so if you are not using it, what you have done will be different from the instructions. Can you please update your question to show what you have done given that you have done something different to the instructions by not using the IBM caching proxy.

Comment: IBM caching proxy is only to to make max persistent request, i am not finding any other purpose of IBM caching proxy. The request which is generating from mqipt1 is receiving at mqipt2 as i can see in the logs. but what is happening between mqipt2 to IBM MQ. I am not able to identify.